# Regex Lookahead and "String End" not working

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I would like to match a String with a look-ahead using the following regex: `/A20.(?!4)/`. This string should match:

```
A20.1
A20.2
A20.3
A20.41
A20.42
A20.400
...
```

The only A20* string that should not match is

```
A20.4
```

It works fine, expect A20.41 or A20.42.. How can I terminate the regex?
I have tried `/A20.(?!4)$/`, but it did not work.

Comment: Move the `$` anchor into the lookahead and escape the `.`, `A20\.(?!4$)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/tr4t1O/1))

Comment: You may need `^A20\.(?!4$)\d+$` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You could use negated character class such as `[^4]`, which would mean "match everything except four". But I think you still want to match only digits, so I'd simply use character class `[123567890]` for that (note that 4 is excluded).

So pattern would be:

```
A20\.[123567890]
```

Also, you use `.` (dot) to match the dot, but dot is special regex character, so you need to escape it to treat it literally: `\.`

Answer (score 0):

you have to look ahead more. If there is another digit behind the 4 then match it, so:

```regex
A20.((?!4)|(?=\d\d))
```